# Check passwords last set date and send notifications in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I send an email automatically when a user has not changed their password in a period of time in SQL Server?

Comment: You can set up a job, run say, one per day, and check the time since passwords changed.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8721/1288 for a query that will let you check the last time a SQL Server login's password was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prerequisite: Configure the Database Email settings, e.g. Email Server, Email Profile, etc.
https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-database-mail-sql-server/

Then schedule a SQL Server Agent Job, run the following scripts to send out an email with users who never change the password in 90 days.

```
begin
 
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'YOUR_EMAIL_PROFILE',
@recipients = 'YourEmail@email.com',
@subject = 'Users Who never change password in last 90 days',
@query = 'SELECT [name], LOGINPROPERTY(name, ''PasswordLastSetTime'') AS PasswordLastSetTime
FROM    sys.sql_logins
where LOGINPROPERTY(name, ''PasswordLastSetTime'') < getdate() - 90',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_header = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'UsersNeverChangePasswordIn90Days.csv'
 
End
```